# div background and border color is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

https://jsfiddle.net/sebastian3495/y3nume0p/28/

For some reason, the styles I applied to the 'main-content' div is not applied and displayed.

Why is that?

The strange thing is that it works perfectly fine on my own personal website: https://gyazo.com/e48cab8526ca2f933587ea52acc0b3f4

```css
div#main-container {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 21px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='main-content'>
  <p>0</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a difference between `main-content` and `main-container` istn it? ;)

Comment: I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in id name in your scss file.  You need to change it to "main-content"

```js
jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(a,b) {
  var ab = [b,a];
  return this.on("click", function(){ ab[this._tog^=1].call(this); });
};


window.onload = function () {

 $("button").clickToggle(
   () => {$("p:nth-child(1)").css("margin-left", "0")},
   () => {$("p:nth-child(1)").css("margin-left", "100px")}
 )

};
```

```css
div#main-content {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 21px solid blue;
}

div > p {
    float: clear;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    height: 100%;
}


div > p:nth-child(n+2) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

div > p:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: purple;
}

div > p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='main-content'>
  <p>0</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>

<button>Click me</button>
```